# How do I get user's full name to display in my Visual Basic application?

Tags: vb.net

How do I get the user's complete name to show up as output after the application runs?
This is a Console application for Visual Basic.

```
' Airline.vb - This program determines if an airline passenger is 
' eligible for a 20% discount. 
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Module Airline 
   Sub Main()
      Dim passengerName As String = ""  ' Passenger's name
      Dim ageString As String = ""      ' String version of passenger's age
      Dim passengerAge As Integer = 0   ' Passenger's age

      ' This is the work done in the housekeeping() procedure 
      passengerName = InputBox$("Enter passenger's name: ")
      ageString = InputBox$("Enter passenger's age: ")

      ' This is the work done in the detailLoop() procedure 
      passengerAge = Convert.ToInt32(ageString)

        ' Test to see if this customer is eligible for a 20% discount 
        If passengerAge <= 7 Then
            System.Console.WriteLine("This person gets a discount!")
            System.Console.ReadLine()
        ElseIf passengerAge >= 7 Then
            System.Console.WriteLine("This person DOES NOT get a discount!!!")
```

The goal of this application is to just display wether or not the user gets a discount based on their age, but I need it to display their **FULL names** as well and it only shows two letters for some reason? I know the solution to this is simple, but im confused at what exactly to do fix this. Any advice?

Comment: try `.WriteLine(passengerName & " gets a discount!"`

Comment: Side note: your logic with the passengerAge is wrong. Both the IF and the ELSEIF will be true if the age of the passenger is 7 years old, as they're both <= and <= (both equals).

Comment: valid point @Keith. Hope you don't mind I added that to my answer with contribution.

Comment: Absolutely no problem, @vba4all

Comment: I tried it and it came out right this time. I also noticed that my logic was flawed as well, so I fixed that right away. Everything works now. I really appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Dim passengerName As String         ' Passenger's name
Dim passengerAge As Integer         ' Passenger's age

' This is the work done in the housekeeping() procedure 
passengerName = InputBox$("Enter passenger's name: ")

' This is the work done in the detailLoop() procedure 
passengerAge = Convert.ToInt32(InputBox$("Enter passenger's age: "))

' Test to see if this customer is eligible for a 20% discount 
System.Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} a discount!", passengerName, IIf(passengerAge <= 7, "gets", "does not get"))
System.Console.ReadLine()
```

Notice how you can shorten the code and eliminate rather a redundant `ageString` variable.

Also as [Keith has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889427/how-do-i-get-users-full-name-to-display-in-my-visual-basic-application#comment42333651_26889427) - Note that only passengers aged above 7 will not get a discount - your original logic was flawed due to `<=7` and `>=7` when the actual age was 7.

Also you can shorten the `If Else` to pretty much one line.